# Identify moving object in the sky at night?

Tags: star, planet, amateur-observing, asteroids, night-sky

Last night in the Carribean, I was looking at the sky at about 8PM EST, and I noticed this really tiny object moving pretty fast from left to right, just between the two stars in the photo. It's very difficult to see and after a while it just disappears.

Somebody told me they had seen it a few days ago going the same exact direction and more or less at the same time.

Can anyone identify this moving object?

I'm including the picture of where I saw it, but you can't see the object. I didn't bother taking a picture while it was moving because it's so tiny that I had trouble finding it myself.

Also, is there a way for an amateur like myself to identify these objects?

[image]

Comment: Try Heavens-Above's [daily predictions for brighter satellites](https://heavens-above.com/AllSats.aspx) and set your location at the upper right of the page.

Comment: Thanks. I've set my location and now I see 20 possible satellites that passed between 8PM and 8:30PM.

Comment: Each of those links to a sky map showing the satellite track. Maybe one of those matches what you saw.

Comment: @rbhat 1) the comment asks you to edit your question and add your approximate location to the question itself. Some readers don't read through all comments, and comments are considered temporary and can be deleted. 2) Rather than "in the Caribbean" it's better if you just put approximate latitude and longitude rather than make each reader go look it up. *Thanks!*

Comment: If it's a direction that's been seen before the most obvious answer is an aeroplane.